# Images Disappear in Running Status on Qt

Tags: image, qt

1. Original design :

   [image]
2. Setting in property :

   [image]
3. When the program is running :

   [image]

All the image inside the project folder "QuickRecorder/Images/MainWindow".
How to solve this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does it happen when you are running from Qt Creator? Or is it just when running the deployed application?

Comment: I run it from Qt Creator all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this the reason almost always is: You use relative path to the image, and the working directory is different when you run the application, and image is not found by the relative path.

To debug, add this to your `main` to print current working directory:

```
qDebug() << QDir::currentPath();
```

A few solutions:

- Use absolute paths (preferably so that you construct them at runtime, for example using [`QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath), instead of hard-coding).
- Put images to [Qt resources](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/resources.html), so they are embedded to the executable.
- Change working directory after application starts (might have unintended consequences if you for example launch child processes, or with file open/save dialogs).

---

Untested, moved from comment to answer: To automatically copy files from the source dir to the build dir, you could add a build step "Custom Process Step" in the Qt Creator project settings. The command you might want to use for the case of this question might be (again, untested):

```
cp -rv %{sourceDir}/QuickRecorder %{buildDir}
```

[image]

Comment: I got "/home/casper/build-Qt_APP-Desktop-Debug".

Comment: So does "/home/casper/build-Qt_APP-Desktop-Debug/QuickRecorder/Images/MainWindow" exist? I suppose not, so that's indeed your problem. You could also just copy that directory to the build dir.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. Is there a method to copy the image files automatically by Qt?

Comment: @CasperLi One way is to add a custom step to the Qt Creator project build, which does something like `cp -rv %{sourceDir}/QuickRecorder %{buildDir}`

Comment: @CasperLi Move the copy command to be done after Make step. Then look at compile output to see why it can't be built, and what command is actually executed.